# How to make function check class instead of text of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/axpbe377/6/

This is the structure of the elements now. **Note: class Name and Text for each span is the same.**

```
<div class='morning_562f7e42757eb'>Morning: 
<span class='Mon'>Mon</span>
<span class='Tue'>Tue</span>
<span class='Wed'>Wed</span>
<span class='Thrs'>Thrs</span>
<span class='Fri'>Fri</span>
<span class='Sat'>Sat</span>
<span class='Sun'>Sun</span>
</div>
```

But I want to change the span text to this now.

```
<div class='morning_562f7e42757eb'>Morning: 
<span class='Mon'>M</span>
<span class='Tue'>T</span>
<span class='Wed'>W</span>
<span class='Thrs'>T</span>
<span class='Fri'>F</span>
<span class='Sat'>S</span>
<span class='Sun'>S</span>
</div>
```

How do I change the script below, to **check for each span's class** that matches data for each user, instead of span's text that matches.

```
$("div.morning_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
        return mornings.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');
```

Comment: `return $(this).hasClass(mornings.join(' '));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use *this.className* instead of *this.innerHTML*

```
$("div.morning_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
    return mornings.indexOf(this.className) > -1;
}).css('color', '#26F525');
```

Comment: One thing should be noted that if the element contain multiple classes, this will not work. Ex. if element contains `class="Mon Something"` then `['Mon', 'Tue'].indexOf('Mon Something')` will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
// From mornings array, create a string.
// The class names are separated by space
// So can be passed directly to hasClass
var strClasses = mornings.join(' ');

$("div.morning_" + user_id + " span").filter(function () {
    // If this element has class from the array, return true
    return $(this).hasClass(strMornings);
}).css('color', '#26F525');
```

---

You can also use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a selector from array and use it directly.

```
"div.morning_" + user_id + " span." + mornings.join(", div.morning_" + user_id + " span.")
```

this will give the selector as

```
div.morning_562f7e42757eb span.Mon, div.morning_562f7e42757eb span.Tue, div.morning_562f7e42757eb span.Sat
```

which can be passed to jQuery object directly.

**Demo:**

```js
var mornings = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Sat'],
  user_id = '562f7e42757eb';
var selector = "div.morning_" + user_id + " span." + mornings.join(", div.morning_" + user_id + " span.");

$(selector).css('color', '#26F525');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='morning_562f7e42757eb'>Morning:
  <span class='Mon'>M</span>
  <span class='Tue'>T</span>
  <span class='Wed'>W</span>
  <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
  <span class='Fri'>F</span>
  <span class='Sat'>S</span>
  <span class='Sun'>S</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a class filter like

```js
var param = 'Mon,Fri',
  user_id = '562f7e42757eb';

var mornings = param.split(',');

$("div.morning_" + user_id + " span").filter(mornings.map(function(value) {
  return '.' + value.trim()
}).join()).css('color', '#26F525');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='1'>

  <div class='morning_562f7e42757eb'>Morning:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

  <div class='afternoon_562f7e42757eb'>Afternoon:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_562f7e42757eb'>Evening:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>


</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div id='2'>

  <div class='morning_562f7eae12fd7'>Morning:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>

  </div>
  <div class='afternoon_562f7eae12fd7'>Afternoon:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_562f7eae12fd7'>Evening:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

or

```js
var param = 'Mon,Fri, Sun',
  user_id = '562f7e42757eb';

var filter = '.' + param.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ', .').trim();


$("div.morning_" + user_id + " span").filter(filter).css('color', '#26F525');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='1'>

  <div class='morning_562f7e42757eb'>Morning:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

  <div class='afternoon_562f7e42757eb'>Afternoon:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_562f7e42757eb'>Evening:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>


</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div id='2'>

  <div class='morning_562f7eae12fd7'>Morning:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>

  </div>
  <div class='afternoon_562f7eae12fd7'>Afternoon:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_562f7eae12fd7'>Evening:
    <span class='Mon'>M</span>
    <span class='Tue'>T</span>
    <span class='Wed'>W</span>
    <span class='Thrs'>T</span>
    <span class='Fri'>F</span>
    <span class='Sat'>S</span>
    <span class='Sun'>S</span>
  </div>

</div>
```